# Use python to compare the values ​in two fields to find the same value?

Tags: python, pandas

this is my CODE

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1], 'B': [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1['OUTPUT'] = df1.duplicated(subset=['A', 'B'], keep=False).map({True: 'OK', False: 'NG'})
print(df1)
```

and the output is this,but is not i want

[image]

i want the output is

[image]

update:
Sorry, this was my mistake. The values ​​in A and B are strings, not numbers.

Comment: Can you explain more what need?

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. The values ​​in A and B are strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need compare values without order use `sorted` or `frozenset` in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df1['OUTPUT'] = (df1[['A', 'B']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated(keep=False)
                                .map({True: 'OK', False: 'NG'}))
print(df1)
   A  B OUTPUT
0  1  2     OK
1  1  2     OK
2  2  3     NG
3  3  4     NG
4  4  4     OK
5  4  4     OK
6  2  1     OK
7  1  2     OK
```

Or use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
df1['OUTPUT'] = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1[['A', 'B']], axis=1), 
                              index=df1.index).duplicated(keep=False)
                                              .map({True: 'OK', False: 'NG'}))
print(df1)
   A  B OUTPUT
0  1  2     OK
1  1  2     OK
2  2  3     NG
3  3  4     NG
4  4  4     OK
5  4  4     OK
6  2  1     OK
7  1  2     OK
```

---

If need compare next with previous rows without ordering compare [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values in helper `Series`:

```
s = df1[['A', 'B']].apply(sorted, axis=1)

df1['OUTPUT'] = (s.eq(s.shift()) | s.eq(s.shift(-1))).map({True: 'OK', False: 'NG'})
print(df1)
   A  B OUTPUT
0  1  2     OK
1  1  2     OK
2  2  3     NG
3  3  4     NG
4  4  4     OK
5  4  4     OK
6  2  1     OK
7  1  2     OK
```

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. The values ​​in A and B are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @Hsien - It working same if numbers or strings

Comment: Because this is not my original data, and because the real data is difficult to provide, I used hypothetical data to ask, but I encountered this problem
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1], 'B': [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1['sorted_values'] = df1.apply(lambda row: sorted([row['A'], row['B']]), axis=1)
df1['OUTPUT'] = df1.duplicated(subset='sorted_values', 
keep=False).map({True: 'OK', False: 'NG'})
df1.drop(columns='sorted_values', inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

This might be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to check for duplicated rows but in any order as well. You can add another column that stores sorted values for each column and use that column to check for duplicates as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1], 'B': [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df1['Sorted'] = df1.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted((row['A'], row['B']))), axis=1)

# Check for duplicates based on the 'Sorted' column 
df1['OUTPUT'] = df1.duplicated(subset=['Sorted'], keep=False).map({True: 'OK', False: 'NG'})

print(df1)
```